# При наведении на выпадающее меню, страница удлиняется, как исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сделал выпадающее меню , однако оно длинное , потому вместе с собой залезает за края сайта , как сделать , чтобы оно было одной длины или чтобы длина сайта увеличивалась пропорционально меню при наведении ?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.all {
    background-image:url(../img/shopORDER1.jpg);
    background-size: cover ;
    flex-grow: 2;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.OTSTUP {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "Marck Script" , cursive ;
    line-height: 140%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top-right {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #C0F400;
}

.top-left {
    float: left;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul,
.menu ol {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu > ul li {
    position: relative;
    border-right: 2px solid #403FD7;
}

.menu > ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: background: rgb(64, 77, 137);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
    padding: 15px 35px 15px 45px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #C0F400;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.menu > ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu > ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    background: rgb(64, 77, 137);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px #1A72E6;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

header img {
    width: 60px;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px; 
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto\9;

}

header, #footer {
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #403F89;

}

header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 1%;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    font-size: 1em;
}

a {
    color:#C524D3;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all.5s ease;
}

.all a {
    color:  #E382FF;
}

.all a:hover {
    color: #C0F400;
}

a:active {
    color: #C4FFFF;
}


/* MENUSHKA */

.menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 150px;
    display: none;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.menu li > ul li {
    border: 1px solid #1A72E6;
}

.menu li > ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: none;
    background: 
}

.menu li > ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    top: 0;

}



/*  Videlenie  */

::selection { background: #FFDEE3; color: #000000;
::-moz-selection { background: #FFDEE3; color: #000000;
::-webkit-selection { background: #FFDEE3; color: #000000; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="Магазин постельного белья и принадлежностей . Мы рады видеть Вас по адресу : г.Ступино, ул. Проспект Победы, д.63/24, торговый центр КБО, второй этаж, павильон 203">
                <title>Заказ</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css">
        <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <header>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
                <div class="logo">
                    <span class="top-left"> <a href="https://vk.com/korolevanochist"> <img src="img/VK.png" alt="Группа ВК" title="Группа ВК"> </a> </span>
                        <a href="Order.html" target="_self" title="Страница заказа" > Заказ </a>
                </div>
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
                        <a href="About.html" target="_self" title="Полезная информация о нашем магазине" class="top-right"> О нас </a>
                        <a href="Main.html" target="_self" title="Главная страница магазина" class="top-right"> Королева Ночи </a>
        </header>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
                <div class="all">
                        <nav class="menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li> <a href="#"> Простыни </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Подушки </a> 
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">50x70cm</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Бамбук ЭКО</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Полупуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 925 со вставкой MEMORY</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 916 двухкамерная</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Перо-пуховая подушка "Неженка"</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">70x70cm</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Полу-пуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Неженка</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эко</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">70x71cm</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Наволочки </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Пледы </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Одеяла </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Наматрацники </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Комплекты </a> </li>
                                </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <p class="OTSTUP"> Как только Вы выбрали , что покупать - свяжитесь с нами по номеру телефона <a href="tel:+79856170617">+79856170617</a> или <a href="tel:+79853384516">+79853384516</a>! </p>
                        <p class="OTSTUP"> Или свяжитесь с нами в <a href="https://vk.com/korolevanochist"> нашей группе ВКонтакте! </a> </p>
                </div>
    </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Все права защищены. Копирование информации и использование в коммерческих целях преследуется по закону &copy; 2018
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас просто плохо рассчитаны ширины пунктов меню. Для того, чтобы задать им динамическую ширину, нужно:

1. `.menu > ul li a {}` уберите боковые паддинги - `padding: 15px 0 15px;`
2. `.menu > ul li {}` добавьте `flex-grow: 1;` и `text-align: center;`

Codepen - https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/pen/yQQoKV

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.all {
    background-image:url(../img/shopORDER1.jpg);
    background-size: cover ;
    flex-grow: 2;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.OTSTUP {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "Marck Script" , cursive ;
    line-height: 140%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top-right {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #C0F400;
}

.top-left {
    float: left;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul,
.menu ol {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu > ul li {
    position: relative;
    border-right: 2px solid #403FD7;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu > ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: rgb(64, 77, 137);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 113, 248) 100%);
    padding: 15px 0 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #C0F400;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.menu > ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu > ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    background: rgb(64, 77, 137);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(64, 77, 137) 55%, rgb(215, 156, 248) 100%);
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px #1A72E6;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

header img {
    width: 60px;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px; 
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto\9;

}

header, #footer {
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #403F89;

}

header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 1%;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    font-size: 1em;
}

a {
    color:#C524D3;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all.5s ease;
}

.all a {
    color:  #E382FF;
}

.all a:hover {
    color: #C0F400;
}

a:active {
    color: #C4FFFF;
}


/* MENUSHKA */

.menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 150px;
    display: none;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.menu li > ul li {
    border: 1px solid #1A72E6;
}

.menu li > ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: none;
}

.menu li > ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    top: 0;

}



/*  Videlenie  */

::selection { background: #FFDEE3; color: #000000;
}
::-moz-selection { background: #FFDEE3; color: #000000;
    }
::-webkit-selection { background: #FFDEE3; color: #000000; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="Магазин постельного белья и принадлежностей . Мы рады видеть Вас по адресу : г.Ступино, ул. Проспект Победы, д.63/24, торговый центр КБО, второй этаж, павильон 203">
                <title>Заказ</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css">
        <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <header>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
                <div class="logo">
                    <span class="top-left"> <a href="https://vk.com/korolevanochist"> <img src="img/VK.png" alt="Группа ВК" title="Группа ВК"> </a> </span>
                        <a href="Order.html" target="_self" title="Страница заказа" > Заказ </a>
                </div>
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
                        <a href="About.html" target="_self" title="Полезная информация о нашем магазине" class="top-right"> О нас </a>
                        <a href="Main.html" target="_self" title="Главная страница магазина" class="top-right"> Королева Ночи </a>
        </header>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
                <div class="all">
                        <nav class="menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li> <a href="#"> Простыни </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Подушки </a> 
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">50x70cm</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Бамбук ЭКО</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Полупуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 925 со вставкой MEMORY</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 916 двухкамерная</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Перо-пуховая подушка "Неженка"</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">70x70cm</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Полу-пуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Неженка</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Эко</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">70x71cm</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Наволочки </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Пледы </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Одеяла </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Наматрацники </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Комплекты </a> </li>
                                </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <p class="OTSTUP"> Как только Вы выбрали , что покупать - свяжитесь с нами по номеру телефона <a href="tel:+79856170617">+79856170617</a> или <a href="tel:+79853384516">+79853384516</a>! </p>
                        <p class="OTSTUP"> Или свяжитесь с нами в <a href="https://vk.com/korolevanochist"> нашей группе ВКонтакте! </a> </p>
                </div>
    </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Все права защищены. Копирование информации и использование в коммерческих целях преследуется по закону &copy; 2018
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Страница продолжает удлиняться при выскакивании меню . Надо достигнуть результата , при котором будет удлиняться страница ( вместе с подвалом )  , либо при котором меню будет заканчиваться внизуперед футером ( так или иначе нужны изменения на длину страницы или футер )